# "InvalidClassException" for "XMLGregorianCalendarImpl" xercesImpl lib under esapi 2.5.2.0

Tags: java-11, xerces, esapi, xmlgregoriancalendar

We are migrating from jdk 8 to 11. We have one of library for esapi version 2.5.2.0 compatible for jdk11. When we have deployed in production server we are getting "InvalidClassException" for "XMLGregorianCalendarImpl". The issue is due to openjdk 11 & xercesImpl lib under esapi having same class XMLGregorianCalendarImpl with two differrent serialVersionUid.

We tried to exclude the xercesImpl from esapi however it is giving classnotfound exception.
Is it possible to suppress the openjdk lib to have the xerces lib take the precendency or any other possible solution?

Comment: You're not supplying enough information to reproduce the issue.  If you can set up a small test app using JDK11 that reproduces this issue, we can help you, but this is one of those issues that can't be solved remotely.

Comment: Agree with @avgvstvs. Need more info. If you look here at our pom (https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/pom.xml#L186-L192) you will see that ESAPI does not pull in any particular version of xercesImpl to begin with. Although running 'mvn dependency:tree' seems to show the problem. It's AntiSamy that's pulling it in and if we want to use the one from the JDK, we will probably need to exclude it from there as well. Our intent was to use the xerces packages from the JDK 7 or later.

Comment: And it would be helpful to show us what you tried in terms of excluding it.

Comment: @KevinW.Wall the XMLGregorianCalendarImpl is part of  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl having serialVersionUid as private static final long serialVersionUID = 3905403108073447394L. Also there is openjdk11 internal package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype having same class XMLGregorianCalendarImpl with private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L.I cannot share the exact code however there is javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller which is unmarshalling the soap message. During that particular time I am getting exception for InvalidClassException

Comment: @KevinW.Wall I tried excluding following ways: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.2.0</version>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
               <groupId>xerces</groupId>
         <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Comment: When the two classes are in two different packages, I can’t understand how they can interfere with each other. Could it be that ESAPI grabs the Xerces one, encounters an unexpected serial version and complains regardless of the presence or absence of the one from JDK?